# Is it fine to create Realm Database with all blank schema on load of React Native application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, realm

Is it fine to create Realm Database with all blank schema on load of react-native application? because if I create schema on the go or as per needed it return error of change reference while opening database.

Comment: What is the error message that you are receiving. Also yes it will be fine to create a blank schema

Comment: @AdamRichardson  please look into error. and It is because I used to open with one schema set in first screen and on second screen I need to open with different schema as I am creating schema on the go.
[Error: Realm at path '/Users/ProT/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E4A8119A-84FB-4BBD-BD19-97F29F90863B/data/Containers/Data/Application/3E4C20E3-8A7F-43E0-920F- already opened on current thread with different schema.]

Comment: You should ensure that you close the realm connection when you have finished with the schema before opening a new schema. If you need to have both open at the same time then you should open the second schema on a different thread

Comment: @AdamRichardson I closed connections already and I have checked that database is already closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to have designed and create all the schema because as per Realm we can not create schema on the go. (i.e on click of a button or on click of any screen load.)